# Display user's name with Brackets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel which display user's full name which user is login with Brackets.

Like..  **(Dhaval Tannarana)**

But some time if User's name length is too big then it Display.

**(Dhaval Tann...**

Here i want to do like this

**(Dhaval Tann...)**

Help me for this

Comment: Can you show us any code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using substringToIndex: we can use NSRange:rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange

```
NSString *name = @"Dhaval Tannarana";     
        if ([name length] > 10) {

                    NSRange range = [name rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){0, 11}];
                    name = [name substringWithRange:range];
                }
    Label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@...)",name];
```

the output:

<kbd>(Dhaval Tann...)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You have to put condition for label width and how many character of string you want to put in your label.

Your Name string :

```
NSString *name = @"Dhaval Tannarana";
```

Now , according width of label you take some character of string with ...

```
   if (name.length > 11)
   {
     name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",[name substringToIndex:11]];
   }

   NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",name];

   labnanme.text = str;
```

**Your Output is**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need two `UILabel` here. One big `UILabel` which is to display `(............)` string.

And one inner label which may be subview for outer label or on top of that label.

So that inner label can actually shows the user name.

You have to maintain width of there labels so that it looks like one label.

[image]

See in the picture yellow label is outer label to show `()` brackets and red label is inner label which shows user name here.